# index.ejs VS index.html

Tags: node.js, express

I recently started learning nodejs and now i am very confused between what to use for my web app, html or ejs (Express). Ejs uses the Express module whereas the .html uses the HTML module. My first question is, what are the differences between them if exact websites can be made from both. The second question, that extends from my first question is what should one use for a website that is to be uploaded to the cloud. .html or .ejs. I believe .ejs is dynamic (if statements can be used inside the file) therefore .ejs should be used. But, on the other hand, its the first time I am hearing this .ejs name, and I am uncertain as to what future it holds, whereas HTML has a build up name, and most developers and the market knows what it is.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ejs is a template engine.

It makes possible for you to load data from your application in the view.

After the template is rendered, it generates a .html file for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: index.ejs allows you to execute JavaScript inside html element. For example: loop or perform arithmetic operation. index.html can't include JavaScript inside its elements.

Answer 2: of course, index.ejs will come to my mind first. If you learn php, it is the same. php developers use index.php instead of index.html

Answer 3: you don't have to worry, there are plenty of supports from JavaScript community today.